# Variance, expectation and linearity.

Tags: statistics

How do I prove that 
$$\mathrm{Var}[ax]=a^2\mathrm{Var}[x]$$ 
Where $x$ is a real random variable and a is a real constant? 
Also what does it mean that the $\mathbb{E}[x]$ is linear? 
Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Use the definition of variance.

Comment: firstly it will be helpful to write the variance in terms of the expectation operators.

A bit more constructive is, the term linear in the context above is that the following property holds $\mathbb{E}(aX) = a\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $\mathbb{E}(x+y) = \mathbb{E}(x) + \mathbb{E}(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation: Random variables are usually capitalized. So, we usually write $Var(X)$ instead of $Var(x)$.

$Var(aX) = \mathbb{E}((a(X-\mathbb{E}(X))^2) = \mathbb{E}(a^2X^2 - 2a^2X\mathbb{E}(X) + a^2 (\mathbb{E}(X))^2)$

Then, using linearity of expectation,

$= \mathbb{E}(a^2 X^2) + \mathbb{E}(-2a^2X\mathbb{E}(X)) + \mathbb{E}(a^2 (\mathbb{E}(X))^2)$

scaling of expectation, and that the expectation of the mean is the mean itself,

$= a^2\mathbb{E}(X^2) -2a^2(\mathbb{E}(X))^2 +a^2(\mathbb{E}(X))^2$

So,

$Var(X) = a^2 \mathbb{E}(X^2) -a^2(\mathbb{E}(X))^2 = a^2Var(X)$

Comment: Thank you very much but I do not really understand how you get from the 2nd row to the 6th row.

Comment: @J.F.H I explained it better.

Comment: I see now. Thank you again @learning